# I need help on using Base chain by coinbase

Tags: solidity, dapps, hardhat, coinbase, layer-2

I wanna use Base chain in my dapp, but i could not get the documentation handy,

1. I did not understand how i use the bridge contract address.
2. Does configuring my `hardhat.config.js` as advised in documentation will do all work? If not what else i do to use Base as a developer?

I am very confused. Please help. And if you explain me with code example then it will be very helpful for me.